# Add An AD Attribute To All Users In an AD Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have a few groups that we are playing with. We'll call it Group1 Group2 Group3. We then have a custom AD Attribute called "team". We need to take all the users of Group1 and change their AD Attribute to  "Group1" etc etc. I've looked at a few ways to do this but am drawing up a blank. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the custom attribute already added to your AD Schema?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few functions to work with here, and this will require that you have the AD module installed for PowerShell.

First, you'll need to get all of the members of the group, and you likely want to do it recursively.  So that's:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group A" -Recursive
```

Running that on its own should give you all the members.  But now you want to do something with what you got back from that function, so you want to loop over them

```
Get-ADGroupMember | ForEach-Object {
     # You'll do something with each member here.    
}
```

And what you want to do it set the AD attribute, which you can do with Set-ADUser. While most attributes can be set easily as they're all properties of the function, yours appears to be custom so you need to use `-replace`.  That looks like this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember | ForEach-Object {
     Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -Replace @{"Team"="Group A"} -WhatIf
}
```

The `-WhatIf` on the end makes the function tell you what it *would* do, but it doesn't actually do it.  I've left it there so you don't accidentally run the code without testing it out first.  When you want this to actually do something, remove that text.

You should try this on a small group with one or two people to make sure it works the way you want, and then when you're ready, hit the larger group

Comment: No need for a `foreach-object` loop, `Get-ADGroupMember` can be piped directly to `Set-ADuser`: `Get-ADGroupMember | where objectClass -EQ user | Set-ADUser ....`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon is absolutely right, it's an old habit that I still haven't gotten past.